# To answer this riddle, what will you open first?

Tags: lateral-thinking

It's 7:00 AM. You are asleep and there is a sudden knock on the door. Behind the door are your parents who came to have breakfast. In your fridge are bread, milk (pasteurized), juice, and a jar of jam.

What will you open first?

Comment: Hello  @Paulette Cooper. What is the original source for this puzzle. I have this sent to me 6 months ago. Thanks

Comment: This is a puzzle that was sent around as a meme on Facebook a while back. I don't think it has a defined source but it's best not to claim it as your own

Answer (score 8):

> **Your eyes**, you will open your eyes first, right?

I'm not sure because the riddle doesn't say much, but here's my guess.

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is

> The question. To answer the riddle you first need to read it by opening the question in PSE

Answer (score 1):

You either open, as @Alto suggested,

> your eyes

or,

> the door of the fridge, if you manage to find it with your eyes closed.

Comment: I'd think you'd open the _other_ door... :)

Answer (score 1):

Other than what the others have said, you might first open your

> Bedroom door

Answer (score 1):

You could first

> Open your bed covers, then your eyes, then your bedroom door, then let your parents in, then open the fridge.