# I need help solving this riddle

Tags: riddle

Riddle: It's 7:00 AM. You are asleep and there is a sudden knock on the door. Behind the door are your parents who came to have breakfast. In your fridge are bread, milk (pasteurized), juice, and a jar of jam. To answer, what will you open first?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is possibly a bit too simple to be well accepted. My advice would be to hang around for a while, try to answer a couple of questions then try posting one. Have fun anyway.

Comment: I think this riddle may be slightly too well-known to be appropriate for this site. Try google?

Comment: What will you close first? This question, because it's a duplicate of [To answer this riddle, what will you open first?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/to-answer-this-riddle-what-will-you-open-first)

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you open is

> The door

Comment: The door must already be open otherwise how would OP know it was his parents? May be the tax collector in which case breakfast is the least of your problems.

Answer (score 2):

I think the first thing you Open is

> Your eyes, in order to wake up.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion:

> I think if this is the situation in his fridge , and his parents came to eat with him, the first thing he needs to open is the phone to order a fine meal from some restaurant ...
> Or alternatively open the window and run away , So they would think he was not home.
> It's his parents at the end of the day, a little respect.

Answer (score 0):

You open:

> your mouth first, to say 'Hello, who's there?' (although you already know it's your parents!)